# How to pass data from activity to another activity on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to pass data from my Login Page to My Detail Page. However the Detail Page cannot accept the data because the String sent in Login Page has null value on Detail Page.

This is my Login Page Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText, editText1;
Button button;
int success = 0;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
JSONObject jsonObject;
HTTPURLConnection service;
String strname ="", strpass="";
String response;
String path = "http://sumbanggagasan.890m.com/select2.php";
Intent intent;
DetailGagasanku detailGagasanku;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nik);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);

    service = new HTTPURLConnection();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && !editText1.getText().toString().equals("")){
                strname = editText.getText().toString();
                strpass = editText1.getText().toString();
                response = null;
                new PostDataTOServer().execute();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class PostDataTOServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    //Create hashmap Object to send parameters to web service
    HashMap<String, String> postDataParams;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        postDataParams=new HashMap<String, String>();
        postDataParams.put("NIK", strname);
        postDataParams.put("pass", strpass);
        //Call ServerData() method to call webservice and store result in response
        response= service.ServerData(path,postDataParams);
        try {
            System.out.println(response + "menu");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            //Get Values from JSONobject
            System.out.println("success=" + jsonObject.get("successs"));
            //success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
            success = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("successs").trim());
            System.out.println("Do in");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Post 1");
        System.out.println(strname);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            System.out.println("Post 2");
            System.out.println(strpass);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(success==1) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent;
            Bundle b;
            b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("username", strname);
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LandingPage.class);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my Details code:

```
public class DetailGagasanku extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView judul, manfaat;
    Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_gagasanku);

    judul = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textJudul);
    manfaat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textManfaat);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    judul.setText(bundle.getString("judul_gagasan"));

    if (bundle != null) {
        if(bundle.containsKey("username"))
        {
            String s = bundle.getString("username");
            manfaat.setText(s);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("not send");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to ask why that username has null value. For your information, that "judul_gagasan" variable can receive value from another activity. I send it from My Adapter.

this is my Adapter code:

```
public class GagasanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GagasanAdapter.GagasanHolder> {

List<String> gagasanList = new ArrayList<>();

public GagasanAdapter(List<String> gagasanList) {
    this.gagasanList = gagasanList;
    Log.v("gagasanSize", "" + gagasanList.size());
}

@Override
public GagasanHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_gagasan, parent, false);
    return new GagasanHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final GagasanHolder holder, final int position) {

    Log.v("Gagasan[" + position + "]", gagasanList.get(position));
    String item = gagasanList.get(position);
    holder.judulGagasan.setText(item);

    holder.judulGagasan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailGagasanku.class);
            intent.putExtra("judul_gagasan", holder.judulGagasan.getText().toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return gagasanList.size();
}

public class GagasanHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView judulGagasan;

    public GagasanHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        judulGagasan = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvListGagasan);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass "username" in Bundle to LandingPage Activity, so you can't access in DetailGagasanku Activity.

So to access "username" in DetailGagasanku Activity, pass username from adapter.